# Camel - Content based routing based on JSON Request body

Tags: json, apache-camel

I have a camel REST endpoint which receives a request of the form:-

```
{"method" : "getHello"}
```

Based on the value in the `method` field in the request body I want to route the request to different routes. So I tried something like this below:-

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/hello").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, RouteRequest.class)
            .choice()
                .when(method(DynamicRouter.class, "route").isEqualTo("getHello")).to("stream:out")
            .otherwise()
                .log("Processing Failed");
```

Dynamic Router class is like below:-

```
public class DynamicRouter {
    public String route(RouteRequest req) { 
        switch (req.getMethod()) {
        case "getHello":            
            return "xxxx";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Even though I am returning `xxxx` from `route()` but the below Predicate is always evaluating to true and it is never going to .otherwise

```
isEqualTo("getHello")).to("stream:out")
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? Also is there some better way of what I am trying to achieve?

I am on `camel 2.16.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected. My `log4j.properties` was not properly configured on the classpath. So the log was not showing up.

Comment: You should probably just delete the question